# An unexpected behaviour in responsive design using HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am learning responsive website designing and came across an unexpected behaviour in my own self tried code of the original.

My mentoring source is this-> [W3 Schools Learning responsive website designing.](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=tryresponsive_col-s)
In that if try to reduce the content for less than 600px every div turns to 100% and cover the whole horizontal position.So I assumed thats the normal behaviour for resposive design.

But in my own self written code,if I try less than 600px it doesn't occupy the whole 100%.It turns into a small chunk box of content.You can check it in the chrome inspect or by resizing. What might have probably gone wrong ? Did I missed any declaration ?

Here is my own self tried code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
[class*="col-"] {
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
}
html {
    font-family: "Lucida Sans", sans-serif;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    /* For tablets: */
    .col-m-1 {width: 8.33%;}
    .col-m-2 {width: 16.66%;}
    .col-m-3 {width: 25%;}
    .col-m-4 {width: 33.33%;}
    .col-m-5 {width: 41.66%;}
    .col-m-6 {width: 50%;}
    .col-m-7 {width: 58.33%;}
    .col-m-8 {width: 66.66%;}
    .col-m-9 {width: 75%;}
    .col-m-10 {width: 83.33%;}
    .col-m-11 {width: 91.66%;}
    .col-m-12 {width: 100%;}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    /* For desktop: */
    .col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
    .col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
    .col-3 {width: 25%;}
    .col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
    .col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
    .col-6 {width: 50%;}
    .col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
    .col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
    .col-9 {width: 75%;}
    .col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
    .col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
    .col-12 {width: 100%;}
}
.box1{
background-color :red;
}
.box2{
background-color :green;
}
.box3{
background-color :blue;
}
</style>
<body>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-4 col-m-12 box1"></div>
<div class="col-4 col-m-12 box2"></div>
<div class="col-4 col-m-12 box3"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trey is correct.  What you are learning here is Mobile First responsive design.  So your base style for mobile is

```
[class*="col-"] { float: left; padding: 15px; }
```

Anything between 0 and 599 will be this style, which is why you have three boxes floated to the left sized at 30px x 30px.

Then when you get to 600 to  767 the tablet media query adds the width styles.

Then after 768 the desktop media query takes over adding new width styles.

In the example you reference they are setting their base mobile style like so

```
 [class*="col-"] { width: 100%; }
```

This is why they get full width columns under 600px.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Lolz... I missed that declaration...Any way you perfectly pointed my fault .Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a media selector for `max-width:600px` and above that you set all of the divs to `float:left` which would cause them to note be 100%, so at <600px your divs only know they should be floating.

Comment: I got what you mean,but how does in my mentoring source overcomes it without declaring max-width as well as declared float:left ?

Answer (score 1):

You should change:

```
[class*="col-"] {
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

to

```
[class*="col-"] {
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

You are currently using only "min-width" with the same values for "desktop" as for "tablets". You do not need second media query. All media query changes are applied from 600px width anyway. Of course keeping separate classes can be handy, but not in the code You have posted. To make less such problems in future I suggest You to use good "CSS reset" and write styles from totality to details (special cases, like media queries usage).